# How do I resolve error message stating "Error in $<-,data.frame: replacement has 0 rows, data has 1352"?

Tags: shiny, shinyapps

I am hoping for some help. I am the newest of the newbees and attempting to make this code work utilizing ShinyApp. Upon running my codes, I am receiving the error message of:
Warning: Error in $<-.data.frame: replacement has 0 rows, data has 1352

Is there anything that appears incorrect with my code that stands out? or any suggestions on next tries?

ui.R Code

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

mobility <- read.csv("mobility_data.csv", sep = ',')
mobility$Date <- as.Date(mobility$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")  
mobility$Province <- as.factor(mobility$Province)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("COVID-19 Mobility Data"),
      selectInput(inputId = "dv", label = "Category",
                  choices = c("Retail_Recreation", "Grocery_Pharmarcy", "Parks", "Transit_Stations", "Workplaces", "Residential"),
                  selected = "Grocery_Pharmarcy"),
      selectInput(inputId = "provinces", "Province(s)",
                  choices = levels(mobility$Province),
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  selected = c("Utrecht", "Friesland", "Zeeland")),
      dateRangeInput(inputId = "date", label = "Date range",
                     start = min(mobility$Date),
                     end   = max(mobility$Date)),
      downloadButton(outputId = "download_data", label = "Download"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput(outputId = "plot"),
      em("Postive and negative percentages indicate an increase and decrease from the baseline period (median value between January 3 and February 6, 2020) respectively."),
      DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)
```

server.R code

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    subset(mobility,
           Province %in% input$provinces &
             Date >= input$date[1] & Date <= input$date[2])})
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly({
      p <- ggplot(filtered_data(), aes_string(x = "Date", y = input$dv, color = "Province")) +
        geom_point(alpha = 0.5) + theme(legend.position = "none") + ylab("% change from baseline")
      p
    })
  })
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    filtered_data()
  })
  
  output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "Mobility_Data.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      data <- filtered_data()
      write.csv(data, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
}
```

Here is the first seven rows from of sample data from my dataset entitled "mobility_data" as well:

```
structure(list(Country = c("Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", 
"Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands"), 
    Province = c("Flevoland", "Flevoland", "Flevoland", "Flevoland", 
    "Flevoland", "Flevoland", "Flevoland"), Date = c("2/15/2020", 
    "2/16/2020", "2/17/2020", "2/18/2020", "2/19/2020", "2/20/2020", 
    "2/21/2020"), Retail_Recreation = c(-2L, -17L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 
    -2L, 4L), Grocery_Pharmarcy = c(-3L, -13L, -6L, -2L, -7L, 
    -5L, -1L), Parks = c(4L, -30L, 3L, 30L, 27L, 3L, 21L), Transit_Stations = c(5L, 
    -9L, -14L, -13L, -15L, -16L, -11L), Workplaces = c(-1L, -7L, 
    -19L, -18L, -18L, -20L, -21L), Residential = c(0L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You should post some sample data in your question so that someone can test and provide a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you! Its my very first time here- Im hoping the data I have added to my initial post is sufficient?

Comment: Your code works fine for me with the sample data you provided.

Comment: After your confirmation, I started a fresh new project and reran my same code in which the error cleared. I have one last item occurring- Now I receive "Warning: Error in subset: object 'mobility' not found"- Any idea why that may be occurring? I feel like Im so close!

Comment: Please read the csv file using `fileInput()`, then you should be able to read the csv file as `mobility` and as a reactive object on the server side.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of how to do that (Im that new to these concepts!)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the csv file using `fileInput`.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("COVID-19 Mobility Data"),
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV file to upload", accept = ".csv"),
      selectInput(inputId = "dv", label = "Category",
                  choices = c("Retail_Recreation", "Grocery_Pharmarcy", "Parks", "Transit_Stations", "Workplaces", "Residential"),
                  selected = "Grocery_Pharmarcy"),
      selectInput(inputId = "provinces", "Province(s)",
                  choices = levels(mobility$Province),
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  selected = c("Utrecht", "Friesland", "Zeeland")),
      dateRangeInput(inputId = "date", label = "Date range",
                     start = min(mobility$Date),
                     end   = max(mobility$Date)),
      downloadButton(outputId = "download_data", label = "Download"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput(outputId = "plot"),
      em("Postive and negative percentages indicate an increase and decrease from the baseline period (median value between January 3 and February 6, 2020) respectively."),
      DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  mobility <- reactive({
    infile <- input$file1
    req(infile)
    return(read.csv(infile$datapath, header=TRUE, sep=','))
  })
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    subset(mobility(),
           Province %in% input$provinces &
             Date >= input$date[1] & Date <= input$date[2])})

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly({
      p <- ggplot(filtered_data(), aes_string(x = "Date", y = input$dv, color = "Province")) +
        geom_point(alpha = 0.5) + theme(legend.position = "none") + ylab("% change from baseline")
      p
    })
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    filtered_data()
  })

  output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "Mobility_Data.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      data <- filtered_data()
      write.csv(data, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```